# Extract rows and calculate average

Tags: r, matrix

I set up 2 problems as follows:

I have two matrices (Mat1 and Mat2). Both matrices are of equal size. I have four output matrices (Output1, Output2, Output3, Output4 respectively) both the same size as Mat1 and Mat2.

Problem 1:

1. In Mat2, Identify the row that contains the maximum value in column1. Lets assume this is row 1.
2. Go to Row 1 of Mat1 and extract the first 3 columns of Mat1 Row1 and store in Output1. Store all other rows in Mat2 for the first 3 columns. At this stage Output1 is 1x3. Output 2 is (n-1)x3.
3. Move to Column 4 of Mat2. Identify the row that contains the maximum value. Lets say this is row 5.
4. Go to row 5 of Mat1 column 4. Store Row5 columns 4,5,6 in Output1. Store all other rows of Mat1 for columns 4,5,6 in Output2.
   ... Repeat this process for all columns in Mat2 following the sequence:1,4,7,9 etc. In this case, i have 25 columns for Mat1 and Mat2, so the sequence will end at 24.

I need to be able to change the sequence from 1,4,7,9 etc, to 1,13,25 etc.

Problem2: 
is equivalent to problem 1, except this time i identify the rows that contain the top-two values in every stage.

1. In Mat2, Identify the rows that contain the top-two values in Column1. Lets say these rows are 2 and 5. Store the first 3 columns of rows 2 and 5 of Mat1 in Output3. Store all remaining rows (column 1-3) of Mat1 in Output4.
2. Move to Column 4 of Mat2. Identify the rows which contain the top two values in column 4 of Mat2. lets say rows 1 and 2.
3. Move to Column 4 of Mat 1. Store column 4,5,6 Row 1 and 2 into Output3. Store all remaining rows in Output4.

Sidenote: This process must be easily extended for matrices with 1000x1000 dimensions. So would prefer not to do this manually.

```
Mat1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol =25, data = rnorm(250,0,1)))
Mat2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol =25, data = rnorm(250,0,1)))

> Mat1
            X1          X2         X3          X4         X5           X6          X7          X8          X9         X10         X11        X12        X13
1  -2.22415466  0.98712728  1.0084356  0.58447183  0.2608830 -0.341029099 -0.71693894 -0.61653058 -0.24790470  0.10777970 -1.68562271 -1.6638535 -0.5538468
2   1.11444365 -0.34865955  0.7518822 -0.07573724  0.1336811 -0.831275643 -0.15564822 -0.68849375 -0.05094047  0.21990082 -0.69879135 -0.6348292  1.0172304
3  -0.05367747  0.08654206 -0.3023270 -0.67335942 -1.1173279  0.004670625  0.52482501  0.78330982  1.18795853 -0.06513613  0.42353439 -0.4152209  1.7174158
4   0.42118984 -0.43257583 -1.3368036  1.64849798  0.8294276  1.256987496 -0.50440892  1.07686292  0.94196135  2.90916270 -0.08714083  0.1094395  1.1715895
5  -0.13720451 -0.94864452  1.9751962 -0.70523555  0.1431405  0.569928767  0.54877505 -0.44571903 -1.16282161 -1.65590032 -0.17710859 -0.8904316  0.3252576
6   0.64336424 -0.38277541 -1.6512377 -0.06542054 -0.1195322  0.666255832  0.60826054  1.88822842 -0.52952627 -0.44776682  0.04321836 -0.6190585 -0.9529690
7  -1.04160098  1.10952094 -0.9186759  0.77437293 -0.2284926 -0.113106151 -0.32092624  1.34157301  2.33813068  1.21812714  0.13165646  0.5532299 -1.3470645
8   1.22940987 -1.26271164 -1.2483658 -2.00578793 -0.6773794 -0.228135998 -0.06223206 -1.97606848  1.67339247 -0.47268196 -0.83544561 -0.3313278 -0.2373613
9   0.08485706 -1.60594589  0.8549923 -0.23394708 -0.5978692 -0.321839877 -0.55298452 -0.08387815 -0.99196489  0.83364114 -0.19579612 -0.8017648 -0.2238073
10 -1.71702699  0.39086484 -0.9974210  0.86232862 -0.2755329 -0.160656438  0.49669949  0.73763073 -0.42380390  1.91208332 -0.27778479  0.7866471  0.1813511

> Mat2
            X1         X2          X3         X4         X5          X6          X7         X8           X9        X10        X11        X12        X13
1   0.11053732 -0.5750170  2.58105259 -1.6895285  0.0508918 -0.54188929 -0.92292169  1.4972970  0.009239807 -0.1706461 -0.8942262 -1.6351505  0.2029262
2  -0.83802776 -0.9322157 -0.34753884  0.8164819  0.7318198  0.09162218  0.15971493 -2.6731067  1.554323641 -0.3161967  0.4622101 -1.9521229 -1.3229961
3   0.61368153 -1.3650360  0.95674229  0.4582117 -0.6959545 -0.59627428  1.94172156  1.6784237 -0.482524695 -0.0514944 -0.4608930 -0.5456863 -0.1340540
4  -1.03156503 -0.2516495  0.76770177 -0.7841354 -3.2404904 -1.76276859  1.57421914  0.9782458 -1.364451438 -0.6437429  0.7485424 -0.8778284  1.7587504
5   0.01183232  0.6825633  1.39634308  1.4136879  0.5166420  0.76930390  0.67210932  1.3007904 -0.284451411  0.5163457  0.3198626  0.8030497 -1.4320064
6  -0.06110883 -0.6762991  0.56105196  0.9767543 -1.0016294 -0.84811626 -0.83319744 -1.1777865 -1.185631394 -0.5673733  0.2956725  0.5425602 -1.0510479
7  -0.56195630  1.3883881  0.09995573  0.6722959 -1.6205290  0.32085867 -0.94243554 -0.2340429 -1.299085265 -0.4433517  0.4424583 -2.8887970  0.1679859
8   1.04612102  0.8360530  0.07005306  0.4818317  1.1857504  0.13649605  1.35261983  0.8008935 -0.101922164  0.6773003 -1.0265770  0.1859912  0.2678461
9   0.88419676 -1.7012899 -1.09656000 -0.4360276  0.6238451 -2.03256276 -1.12575579  1.8407234  0.522372401 -0.6229582  0.6727720 -0.5695190  0.6298388
10 -0.68648649 -0.6689894 -0.56849261 -1.9012760  1.1418180  0.46377789 -0.08107475  1.4378120 -1.489367198 -0.7682887 -0.2858680  0.9584056  1.3178700
```

So for example:

```
which.max(Mat2[,1]) # 8
```

so go to row 8 of `Mat1` and store the first 3 cols in `Output1`.

```
Output1[1, 1:3] #  1.22940987 -1.26271164 -1.2483658
```

Store all other rows of `Mat1` for cols 1 to 3 in `Output2`.

```
which.max(Mat2[, 4]) # 5
```

implies

```
Output1[1, 4:6] # -0.70523555  0.1431405  0.569928767
```

And so on and so forth.

Comment: Are you sure Mat1 and Mat2 are supposed to look like that? Does it have to be a data.frame or should it be a matrix after all?

Comment: @RonakShah adjusted. That was what i meant.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach it's meant to be a data.frame. I'm not sure how to create a reproducible example in a good way.

Comment: that helps already, ideally when using rnorm you set a seed so we can get the same numbers. is rnorm supposed to be 2500 elements or 250?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach it's just there to fill the matrix. The data isn't important

Comment: Shouldn't `Output1[1, 1:3] # -2.22415466  0.98712728  1.0084356` be `Output1[1, 1:3] # 1.22940987 -1.26271164 -1.2483658`?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach i'm sorry yes you're right.

Comment: Lat question, it sounds like we are always appending columns, won't Output 1 be of dimension 1, length(sequence) and output 2 or dimension nrow(Mat2), length(sequence)?

Comment: or more like top_n, length(sequence), nrow(mat2)-top_n, length(sequence)

Comment: Sorry you've made me realise another point.

Output 1 should be 1 x 25 and Output 2 should be (10-1)x25 in this example. So repeat the process all the way up to Seq1 ==21, and store 3 entries from that. and then when seq1=24, just take the 1 entry that remains. Is that clear? So like in every case store 3 entries if possible, otherwise store the remainder that's left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
Juggle <- function(m1, m2, col, step, top_n = 1) {
  if (length(col) == 1) {
    output_rows <- sort(m2[, col], index.return = TRUE, decreasing = TRUE)$ix
    col_idx <- seq(col, col + step - 1)
    top_idx <- seq(top_n)
    bottom_idx <- seq(top_n + 1, nrow(m2))
    max_out <- m1[output_rows[top_idx], col_idx]
    rest_out <- m1[output_rows[bottom_idx], col_idx]
    return(list(max_out = max_out, rest_out = rest_out))
  } else {
    left <- Juggle(m1, m2, col[1], step, top_n)
    right <- Juggle(m1, m2, col[seq(2, length(col))], step, top_n)
    return(list(
      max_out = cbind(left$max_out, right$max_out),
      rest_out = cbind(left$rest_out, right$max_out)
    ))
  }
}
```

`m1` and `m2` are the matrices or data frames.
`col` is a single or sequence of columns like 1, 4, 7, 9 or 1,13,25.
`step` is the amount of columns to extract.
`top_n` is the amount of rows to extract.

This will return a list with components max_out for the top_n row extracts and rest_out for the N-top_n row extracts.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Sorry for the poor explanations.